# Fitting a simple polynomial to different possibilites

Tags: polynomials, regression

I have a few sets of numbers. For example, let's say my sets are -

> 1,5,8,12,25
>
> 2,14,36,45,47
>
> 5,9,17,55,80
>
> 29,37,64,93,102
>
> 48,69,77,86,167

Given these sets, I want to fit a polynomial such that when x=1, at least one of the 5 elements in my first row is the result. When x=2, at least one of the elements in my second row should be the result and so on.

So when x goes from 1->5, the result of the polynomial should for each x should satisfy at least one element from the corresponding row.

The polynomial I am looking for should be of an order much smaller than the number of data sets.

A brute force method to try all possibilites is difficult and very computation intensive.

Comment: What's the problem?  You can find a polynomial such that $p(1)=1,p(2)=2,p(3)=5, p(4)=29, p(5)=48$ if you want...

Comment: [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=PolynomialInterpolation%5B%281%2C1%29%2C%282%2C2%29%2C%283%2C5%29%2C%284%2C29%29%2C%285%2C48%29%5D) has [Lagrange Interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial) implemented as PolynomialInterpolation[].

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear enough. The polynomial I am looking for should be of an order much smaller than the number of data sets. I'll edit the post now

Comment: If the data sets are "randomly" produced, there won't be any polynomial of lower degree that gets the job done.  Of course, it's possible that the data is produced in some way that makes such a polynomial more probable.  In that case, perhaps the nature of the dependence between the data sets could help.

Comment: Wait, Lagrange Interpolation just fits a polynomial to a fixed set of numbers. I want a polynomial where there are n choices as the result of the polynomial for each value of x and as long as any one of these n are the result, it is totally fine.

Comment: Sure, I get the problem.  But it still won't work generally.  Suppose you have three data sets.  Then you are hoping for a linear polynomial that works.  Well, there are only a finite number of linear polynomials that work for the first two sets...hence there are only finitely many values $p(3)$ might take.  The probability (however defined) that a random list of real numbers (or integers, or whatever) happens to include one of those values is $0$.